# F# returning a value from a function that returns unit

Tags: f#, return-type

I have a type

```
type figure =
{
   what : int;
   position : Point;
   size : Point;
}
```

and i want my function to return this type, however since it's an event it wants to return a unit ()
how can i get my function to return this type instead of unit?

```
let checkInput = 
drawArea.MouseClick.Add(fun args -> 
    if args.Button = MouseButtons.Left then 
        new figure { what = 0; position = new Point(args.X, args.Y); size = new Point(50, 50) })
```

any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Even if it were possible to make your function return a figure and still pass it to `Add`, `Add` couldn't possibly do anything with the return value, so it would just be ignored.

Comment: @sepp2k what i want to do is have a function that checks for mouseclick, then take the position from the where the mouse was clicked and store it to my figure. Then return the figure to another function. It's not ment to be passed to `Add`

Comment: But you are passing it to `Add`. If you don't want to pass it to `Add` then don't and you'll be free to return whatever you want. The thing is: clearly you want your function to be called when the mouse is clicked and not at a specific time when you manually invoke it from your own code. So where exactly do you want the figure to be returned to?

Comment: `Add` is just a callback, How would i else detect a mouseClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the compiler doesn't know what to do with the new figure you created.  Figure needs to be stored somewhere or passed to a function.  Here's an example where it's passed to a function.  When you click in the form the title is updated to the clicked position.

```
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

type Figure = {
   what : int;
   position : Point;
   size : Point;
}

let drawArea = new Form()

let print figure =
    drawArea.Text <- figure.position.ToString()

drawArea.MouseClick.Add(fun args -> 
    if args.Button = MouseButtons.Left then 
        print { what = 0; position = Point(args.X, args.Y); size = Point(50) }
)

Application.Run(drawArea)
```

You will need to include these two assemblies under references in your project for this example.

```
System.Drawing
System.Windows.Forms
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect reason to use a reference cell - like this

```
let fig = ref None
let checkInput = 
drawArea.MouseClick.Add(fun args -> 
    if args.Button = MouseButtons.Left then 
        fig := Some(new figure { what = 0; position = new Point(args.X, args.Y); size = new Point(50, 50) }))
```

Then you can just check the value of the reference cell using

```
match !fig with
|Some(t) -> //do something
|None -> //mouse hasn't been clicked
```

Comment: That seemse the way to go! Thank you!